# JQuery -- I want to click a word to change it then click it again to change it back

Tags: jquery, toggle, switch-statement

I want users to be able to click on 'Hello!' to make it change to 'Goodbye!' and then click it again to change it back to 'Hello!'. I've got as far as making 'Hello!' change to 'Goodbye!', but I don't know how to make the function 'repeat'.

I'm an extreme novice at this, so all help and advice is welcome!

This is as far as I've got:

HTML:

```
<body>
   <p id = "greeting">Hello!</p>
</body>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#greeting").click(function(){
        $(this).text('Goodbye!').toggle(hide);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#greeting").click(function(){
     $(this).text(function(_, oldText) {
         return oldText === 'Goodbye!' ? 'Hello!' : 'Goodbye!';
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DPeWk/

Comment: Can you explain me this line : $(this).text(function(_, oldText)

Comment: `text` method callback function accepts 2 parameters, the first one is the `index` of the current element in jQuery collection and the second one is the current `textContent` of an element, whatever you return from the function will be the new text content of the element.

Comment: Good, but at the place of index, you passed _, what's the meaning of this?

Comment: @DeadMan - The value of `index` is inconsequential in this case, so named it `_` to show lack of importance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it using `toggle`:

The HTML

```
<body>
    <p>Hello!</p>
    <p style="display: none">Goodbye!</p>
</body>
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("p").click(function () {
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zcQkD/2/

There is an example very similar to this on the jQuery docs for toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: We are looking for proper and logical answers here, not any short tricks like your answer.

Comment: The asker said he wanted to be able to `click 'Hello!' to make it change to 'Goodbye!'`, and this does just that. He said he was a novice and all help/advice was welcome, so even if it is a 'short trick', it is a valid way to do this in jQuery and it could be something he could find use from.

Comment: Ok, if you just believe in short tricks then i take by downvote back. You will have to edit answer so i can take my downvote back, because my vote is locked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
$("#greeting").click(function(){
if ($(this).text() == "Hello!")
   $(this).text("Goodbye!")
else
   $(this).text("Hello!");
});
```