# Different function according to selected word -- JQuery

Tags: jquery, input

**I believe my question was unclear originally. I'm striving to make it clearer here.**

My question—How do I tell JQuery to identify which of the two words the user has selected so it changes the  background-color to different colors for 'Hello' and 'Goodbye'? There is a 'button' that users click to have this happen.

I'm building a site where users can click on words on the page to change them. In this case—thanks to some great help on this forum—users can choose between 'Hello' and 'Goodbye'.

In other words, if a user chooses 'Hello!', I want the background to be green. If they choose 'Goodbye!', I want it to be blue.

I'm really stuck :/

I'm very new to this, so all help appreciated greatly!

The code I'm using to do the background-color change:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
        if ($("#greeting").text === 'Hello!') {
            $("body").css("background-color", "green");
        }
        else {
            $("body").css("background-color", "blue");
        }
});
```

And here is the remainder of the site's code (thanks to help in a previous question!):

```
<body>
   <p id = "greeting">Hello!</p>
</body>
```

And here is my JQuery (see previous question!):

```
$(function(){
    $("#greeting").click(function(){
        $(this).text('Goodbye!').toggle(hide);
    });
});
```

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446920/jquery-i-want-to-run-a-function-according-to-the-on-page-text

Comment: This is still the same code as in [your first question on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446454/jquery-i-want-to-click-a-word-to-change-it-then-click-it-again-to-change-it-b). Why don't you try taking into account the answer you accepted there and see how far it gets you before asking again?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi--Sorry, still new to this forum. Decided not to post my failed attempts at making it work. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

try this once.I am also not sure

```
$(function(){
    $("#greeting").click(function(){

       if($(this).text() =="Hello")
        $(this).text('Goodbye!').toggle(hide);

      if($(this).text() =="Goodbye")
        $(this).text('Hello!').toggle(hide);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I believe my question was unclear, but your respons was very helpful. I've tried to implement it (at least, a variation of it), but I still can't make it work. See my amendments to the original question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#greeting").click(function(){
        if($(this).text() == 'Hello') {
           $(this).text('Goodbye!');
        } else {
           $(this).text('Hello');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Still can't quite crack it :/ Probably my fault for vague question with no workings. See my amendments. Thanks a lot, though!